# Is there a special 'trick' to Mmm, Cookies?

Tags: support, winter-bash, cookies, winter-bash-2022

I cannot get what would seem to be one of the simplest hats to achieve - Mmm, Cookies!

I usually run all kinds of ad, content, cross-site tracker prevention & cookie blockers, so I switched off all I could. Discarded Stack Exchange cookies, logged out & re-launched.

I see the Cookie popup, so I open it & edit the contents. If I try to log in first, the pop up disappears. I even tried logging into the same site on another tab, but it seems I must deal with the cookie popup before login.

Still no hat.
Then as I was doing all this, across three different browsers eventually, I got the hat on here, Meta SE.
I still don't know exactly what I did to get it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm sorry you're struggling to get the hat. The method is designed to help users *find* the cookie settings modal without them needing to change the selections in them. So the method is to click the "Cookie Settings" option in the footer, which will open the modal... and that's it. It's not required to change anything or even confirm the choices, you can just x out of the modal and you should get it.

Hopefully this will help but please let us know if you still can't get the hat in a (relatively) unmodified browser. I have uBlock Origin running and I don't have issues getting the hat.

[image: Cookie settings modal and greyed-out footer with the item "cookie settings" circled with a red freehand circle.]

Comment: Ah - once I'd disabled most of my 'interceptors' again & directly clicked that link, it worked. I think I was relying on the pop-up which happens after a cookie clear [& is usually suppressed]. I did get the idea was to get people to pay attention to the options… but I had completely missed that there was a specific link to it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: nice freehand sailboat! :D

Comment: its not working for me. I tried many browsers in which I had never logged in with stack overflow credentials